# Error "loading" the phpMyAdmin environment in my browser

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm having trouble logging into my phpMyAdmin server database.

Here's an album with a few pictures of the error I'm getting. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLyIz.jpg

Whenever I open phpMyAdmin in my browser I get the first picture, the normal login screen but with a login section for the sidebar, and the main content. I have to log into each separately (as shown on the second/third picture), and when I do the environment looks completely different, like it isn't styled at all and just html/php. Normally when I log in it looks like the normal phpMyAdmin environment like in the pictures on this tutorial https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin_administration.htm

I've been using this database for a few months now and never had this problem. It was working last friday, but just started doing this this week.

I've looked around on the internet but I can't find anything helpful, I'm a bit of a noobie too when it comes to php and databases. Thanks for any help in advance!

Edit: I've tried uninstalling / reinstalling phpmyadmin on my server and now I'm getting the following error "Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly.". If I refresh the page I go back to the duel-login page as before

Comment: what is your server configuration  ?Xamp ? Apache ? On f12 console are you getting any errors ?

Comment: My guess is you URL or folder path have changed, and your borwser cannot find linked `.css`(thats why it looks so empty) and `.js` (which phpMyadmin uses a lot)

Comment: I'm using Apache and getting 4 "SyntaxError: Unexpected Token <" console errors

Comment: @Florian How would you best suggest to fix that?

Comment: I'm not an expert in phpMyAdmin, but mabye you can add / modify the  header in the html. If you can, look out for the `<base` tag http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp and modify it accordingly.
This tag serves as a "root" for all additional files to be donwloaded by the browser, like your `.css` and `.js` files